# Using for loop to extract string from a list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings as shown below.

```
rec = ['Class',
 'science',
 'boy',
 'girl',
 'cat',
 'dog']
```

I want to use a for loop to extract the strings from the list above, here is the code that I have.

```
try:
    fic_1 = rec[0]
except:
    fic_1 = ''
try:
    fic_2 = rec[1]
except:
    fic_2 = ''
try:
    fic_3 = rec[2]
except:
    fic_3 = ''
try:
    rc_1 = rec[3]
except:
    rc_1 = ''
try:
    rc_2 = rec[4]
except:
    rc_2 = ''
try:
    rc_3 = rec[5]
except:
    rc_3 = ''
```

Since hard code it, that's why I use the try and expect. I am trying to use for loop but I am having hard time on how to do it. I can think of using `for i in range(len(rec)):` but don't know how to apply it to my code. I am wondering how can I solve it by using for loop instead of hard coding it.

I am going to reuse those strings later, so I would love to write a for loop that can convert those strings into 6 different string objects

Thanks!!

Comment: `for string in rec: print(string)`?

Comment: `for i in range(len(rec)): print(rec[i])` go through list in python

Comment: What are you trying to do? You're extracting the items into different variables for what purpose? Are you going to use them later?

Comment: @ZWang Yes, I am going to use them later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to create a similar list of keys or values you want to map the inputs in your `rec` list too and combine them into a dictionary like so:

```
keys = [
    'fic_1',
    'fic_2',
    'fic_3',
    'rc_1',
    'rc_2',
    'rc_3']
    
combined = {keys[i]:rec[i] for i in range(len(rec))}
# {'fic_1': 'Class', 'fic_2': 'science', 'fic_3': 'boy', 'rc_1': 'girl', 'rc_2': 'cat', 'rc_3': 'dog'}
```

If you just want to iterate over the list you can do a for loop over the list:

```
for word in rec:
    print(word)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but if I do not want to convert them into a dict, are there any ways for me to use. I am hoping to convert those strings into an individual string objects, in this case, it will have 6 string objects

Comment: @DataWizard Why not keep it as a list? They are already strings, just stored in a list.

Comment: Please learn about dicts. You can use them directly and it's much easier. For example, if you use his method, you can call `fic_1` by simply going `combined[fic_1]`

Comment: @ZWang, you are right, I need to learn more about dicts. Thank you so much!!